# Find the type of a deprecated AMI by its ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a CloudFormation script that specifies an AMI ID. Now I get `API: ec2:RunInstances Not authorized for images: [ami-1523bd2f]` so apparently [I need to update my AMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653307/aws-ami-deprecation-api-ec2runinstances-not-authorized-for-images).

But I have forgotten the type of the machine, or the CloudFormation script was created by someone else. And since I can't create an instance due to this error, I can't just lookup the OS and version from inside of it. I have to go entirely from the AMI ID, how do I find out which OS and version it points to?

Comment: There is no way to find the information you are asking for unless there s some metadata (description) associated with the AMI.

Comment: @helloV Well, that answers my question, I guess.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595119/how-to-find-out-information-about-an-ec2-instance-from-ami-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A search on the web shows the AMI to be:

```
Windows_Server-2012-RTM-English-64Bit-SQL_2012_SP1_Web-2014.02.12 (ami-1523bd2f)
```

Therefore, just do a search in the AMI section of the EC2 console for:

```
Windows_Server-2012-RTM-English-64Bit-SQL_2012
```

This will show available images.

It appears that the original image was Service Pack 1 (deprecated), while current images are listed as SP2 and SP3.